# How can I uninstall ubuntu on a school laptop?

Tags: software-uninstall

I recently installed Ubuntu on a school laptop, I still have windows OS, i can choose to load Ubuntu, or Windows. So I guess it's running on the side? I'm not very tech savvy, and I want to uninstall ubuntu and it's partitions without losing the Windows OS; if that's possible.. when I shut it down then turn it on it sometimes boots into ubuntu automatically.

Comment: Look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) for help

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the ubuntu partition inside windows.

Steps:

1.Go to Start, right click Computer, then select Manage. Then select Disk Management from the sidebar.

2.Right-click your Ubuntu partitions and select "Delete". Check before you delete!

3.Then, right-click the partition that is on the Left of the free space. 
Select "Extend Volume". Go through the Wizard and Finish it.

4.Done

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't have an admin account on the School's laptop, in the Windows side?  If you did have Windows admin power, you could launch the admin tools for  disks and just reformat the partitions that Windows sees, but cannot recognize.

If you don't have windows admin power, I think the easiest thing to do is get the Ubuntu "live" install USB and restart from that.  Don't re-start the install, just let it launch an interactive session. If you get that far, there are many ways to destroy the partitions you want to get rid  of.  How to do this depends a bit on the kind of partition table you have. Is PC slightly older BIOS or newer UEFI with the fancier partition structure. If you on older version, run "/sbin/fdisk -l" and use that to view disks and partitions, then something like "/sbin/fdisk /dev/sda" will give you clear path to get rid  of partitions on the first hard disk. "/dev/sdb" for the second hard disk. Its pretty obvious what needs to happen.

The interesting question in my mind is what will MS Windows do after you obliterate the Linux partitions. Will it start? I think the answer depends on how you installed Ubuntu and where you put the boot loader.  If the boot loader is in the master boot record, this might be interesting trouble. If could be you destroyed the Windows boot loader.  If the boot loader is in the partition where Linux is installed, I think not so dangerous.

If the Windows partition can't boot, you will have to go ask for help in a Windows community page. Don't be brave enough to ask here.  You won't have any eyebrows after the scorching stops.

Comment: I can't access the tools to the disk, I have command prompt and Windows PowerShell, do you think I would be able to delete it from there?